# Creating JsonPath for variable length JsonArray to copy data in redshift

Tags: json, amazon-redshift, jsonpath

I have json of this kinds structure

```
 {
    "user_id": "12345678",
    "users": [
        ["user1", 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, "A"],
        ["user2", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, "B"],
        ["user3", 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, "C"]
    ]
 }
```

where users array length can be variable . I want to use copy command to load data in Redshift table where in columns are

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['user_id']",
        "$['users'][*][0]",
        "$['users'][*][1]",
        "$['users'][*][2]",
        "$['users'][*][3]",
        "$['users'][*][4]",
        "$['users'][*][5]",
        "$['users'][*][6]"
    ]
}
```

I have tried using * but indexoutofbound i got. I searched aws documents and many stackoverflow links but could not succeed.
Please give any suggestion or methods.

Comment: I know using * as above is wrong because it returns all results at once but i dont know how to upload whole array , do i have to break  them into individual json?

Comment: It turns out you cannot, at the moment, use wild cards within your jsonpath file. You are better off converting the `json` objects into a `csv` and upload them into

Comment: is this issue fixed . please let me know i'm also facing same problem